# Arduino on MacOS disabled my USB ports

Tags: macos, arduino, serial-port

Trying to test my program. Plugged my arduino in. Got a message saying it's drawing too much power and the USB ports have been disabled. Now when I go to tools > port, the "serial port" option is grayed out. I've tried powering the arduino with the 9v battery, but the battery started to get hot, so I disconnected it again. I've found solutions for this on Linux and Windows but as far as I can tell absolutely nobody uses macOS if they don't have to. It just so happens that I have to.

Comment: This is more suited for [apple.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. More info is available in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

The MacOsx protect USB ports, disconnecting if the current drain is too high. Its good to not burn the USB port.

The fact of battery is get hot, indicates that your board is consuming much current. Can be a short cut, deffect in board, or in any that you plugged in Arduino.

Please try connect the Arduino without any wire connections in battery,
if still get hot, your Arduino board has burn-out and must be replaced.